# The canonical map from the group algebra to the set of endomorphism of a vector space is surjective

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group. Suppose $\pi:G \rightarrow GL(V)$ be an irreducible representation of $G$. This representation gives a canonical map
$$\tilde{\pi}: \mathbb{C}[G] \rightarrow End(V)$$ where End(V) denotes the set of linear maps on $V$. Prove that $\tilde{\pi}$ is surjective.
I have no clue about the solution. There is a hint given that if we consider on the contrary that $\tilde{\pi}$ is not surjective we will get a linear functional on $End(V)$ which is zero on the image of $\tilde{\pi}$, which will contradict some kind of orthogonality relation. I have no idea where this hint leads to. I also don't have any other idea to solve. A little help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: I wasn't particularly happy with the answer that I provided. It seems that I don't understand the proof myself. So I decided to delete it. One reference for this result is Proposition 10 in Chapter 6 of Serre's Linear Representations of Finite Groups (page 48). But the proof there also does **not** elaborate on the part you are interested in, unfortunately. Hopefully someone will provide a detailed answer!

Comment: The way I prefer to prove the orthogonality relations (for $G$ finite) involves using the surjectivity of that map along the way. I prove injectivity and use $\hom_G(\Bbb CG,V)\cong V$ with Schur's lemma to prove the equality $\sum_{{\rm Irr}(G)}(\dim V)^2=|G|$, which establishes bijectivity.

Comment: @arctic tern I didn't understand!!  Are you suggesting a proof of the question?

Comment: Sure, I mention some details of a proof that $\bar{\pi}$ is a bijection, but also I'm saying the proof surely doesn't match what is intended because I use $\bar{\pi}$'s bijectivity to establish the orthogonality relations instead of vice-versa, so I'm not sure if it's relevant to you.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this is not the intended solution, but I still want to point out that the result can be obtained from the Artin-Wedderburn Theorem which explains the structure of semisimple algebras. The group algebra $\mathbb{C}G$ is a semisimple algebra and as such is the direct product of simple algebras. Each of these is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ for some $n$ and each of these corresponds to an irreducible representation. In fact, $\mathbb{C}^n$ with its usual action is a simple $\Bbb{C}^{n \times n}$-module. The corresponding representation is essentially the identity map $\mathbb{C}^{n \times n} \cong \text{End}(\Bbb C^{n})$. Thus, the isomorphism $\mathbb{C}G \cong \prod_{i = 1}^h \mathbb{C}^{n_i \times n_i}$ is nothing else than the map $\Bbb{C}G \to \prod_{i = 1}^h \text{End}(\Bbb C^n)$. As it is a bijection, the projections $\Bbb{C}G \to \text{End}(\Bbb C^n)$ are surjective.

Comment: Is there any without using the Artin-Wedderburn theorem? Can you tell me how to use the hint?

Comment: Is there any news concerning direct proof of surjectivity?

Comment: Analogously to Mathias Klupsch argument on semisimplicity of $\mathbb{C}G$ one can use the fact that $|G| = \sum_{{\rm Irr}(G)}\dim^2 V$ to prove that the natural algebra homomorphism $\mathbb{C}G \to \prod_{V_i\in {\rm Irr}(G)}{\rm End}(V_i)$ is an isomorphism. Then as pointed out by Mathias $\mathbb{C}G \to \prod_{V_i\in {\rm Irr}(G)}{\rm End}(V_i) \twoheadrightarrow  {\rm End}(V_i)$. However this probably not along the lines of your hint.